# How can you detect when HTML rendering is completed in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, rendering, loading

I've done extensive research on this subject, but no matter what I do, I find it extremely difficult to achieve this objective.

I want to execute code when all elements have been fully rendered in AngularJS web application. I think I found solution suggesting to use routers and views, but I could not make that work on my case, as it seems it requires certain configuration.

When you have `ng-repeat` and a lot of nested `directives` that will generate HTML/Content based on various conditions using `ng-if`, I noticed that HTML rendering continues even after document ready event is fired or view content have been loaded ie `$viewContentLoaded` event is triggered.

The closest idea I have is to use `$watch` over the length of the children of the element of a given `directive`. Every time the `$watch` is executed, increment counter `renderCount`. Then, in another timer event, check if the counter `renderCount` didn't change over the past say 3-5 seconds, then we can make an assumption that rendering is done.

The code to watch for the children, and check if no more rendering is taking place, could be as follows:

```
app.directive('whenRenderingDone',  function($interval, $parse){
    return {
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var renderingCount = 0;
            function watchForChildren() {
                scope.$watch(function(){
                    return $(':input', el).length;
                }, function(newVal, oldVal){
                    if (newVal) {
                        renderingCount++;
                    }
                })
            }
            watchForChildren();
            //Check counter every 3 seconds, if no change since last time, this means rendering is done.
            var checkRenderingDone = $interval(function(){
                var lastCount = lastCount || -1;
                if (lastCount === renderingCount) {
                    var func = $parse(attrs.whenRenderingDone);
                    $interval.cancel(checkRenderingDone);
                    func(scope);
                }
                lastCount = renderingCount || -1;
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

I will try to implement the above approach, and if you have feedback please let me know.

Tarek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed the following directive which is working well under Chrome and IE11:

```
app.directive('whenRenderingDone',  function($timeout, $parse){
    return {
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var lastCount;
            var lastTimer = 5000; // Initial timeout
            //Check counter every few seconds, if no change since last time, this means rendering is done.
            var checkRenderingDone = function (){
                var mainPromiseResolved = scope.mainPromiseResolved;
                lastCount = lastCount || -1;
                if (lastCount === el.find('*').length && mainPromiseResolved) {
                    console.log('Rendering done, lastCount = %i', lastCount);
                    var func = $parse(attrs.whenRenderingDone);
                    func(scope);
                } else {
                    lastCount = el.find('*').length;
                    console.log('mainPromiseResolved = %s, lastCount %i', mainPromiseResolved, lastCount)
                    console.log('Rendering not yet done. Check again after %i seconds.', lastTimer/1000.00);
                    stopCheckRendering = $timeout(checkRenderingDone, lastTimer); 
                    lastTimer = lastTimer - 1000;
                    if (lastTimer <= 0) {
                        lastTimer = 1000;
                    }
                    return stopCheckRendering;
                }
            }
            var stopCheckRendering;
            stopCheckRendering = checkRenderingDone();
            el.on('$destroy', function() {
                if (stopCheckRendering) {
                    $timeout.cancel(stopCheckRendering);
                }
              });
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this will be of help to you, and if you have any comment to improve, please let me know. [See this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B97clwYte2SHMWFkWEp2Zm45Z3c) to give you an idea about how it is working.

Tarek

Comment: The directive is beefy, but it would help if you included a "how to use" along with it.

Comment: That was a long time ago! I think you need to place `whenRenderingDone` as an attribute on a higher level on the DOM and it seems you can assign this attribute a function to call when rendering is calculated as done. I will see if I remember more details. The `mainPromiseResolved` is global and used to ensure the main work is done as another safety check. It is optional I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$$postDigest` to run code after the digest cycle completes. You can read more about the scope lifecycle [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)

```
// Some $apply action here or simply entering the digest cycle
scope.$apply(function () { ... });
...
scope.$$postDigest(function () {
  // Run any code in here that will run after all the watches complete
  // in the digest cycle. Which means it runs once after all the 
  // watches manipulate the DOM and before the browser renders
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. However, I remember that any AngularJS API that starts with `$$` is not 100% safe to use, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, your solution didn't work for me. See my solution above so that you will have better idea about what I am trying to do. Thanks!